# How to use the draw and keyTyped() function at the same time?

Tags: javascript, audio, project, draw, p5.js

I want to create a code where when I click a key on the keyboard it will play music and draw a rectangle. I have managed to add music using the `keyTyped()` function but I am not sure how to add a rectangle to the canvas.

How to use the draw and `keyTyped()` function at the same time?

Comment: You can add the `rect()` function inside the `keyTyped()` function, right after your code for playing music, and it should work.

Answer (score 0):

Something like this:

```
function setup() {
  createCanvas(400, 400);
  background("white");
}

function keyTyped(){
  
  //play sound
  
  fill("black");
  
  rect(50, 50, 100, 100);
  
}
```